# How do I revert to original installation of Apache2

Tags: apache

Okay so a long time ago I was recklessly changing stuff in my Apache2 folder and now I don't know what's wrong and I don't want to take the time to figure it out. I just want to delete folder and then reinstall it with the factory defaults. Is there a way I can do that without doing a complete backup and then reinstalling OSX?

Answer (score 0):

Completely remove all Apache2 packages with purge option.

```
apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils
```

Then install again

```
apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: I don't have apt-get though

Answer (score 0):

I decide to just backup my hard drive and do a clean install of OSX